# Is stateful processing possible with the apache beam python sdk?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, stateful

I have been following the [Timely (and Stateful) Processing with Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html) article and though comprehensive and well written it does not specify how to achieve the same with python. More specifically 
it states:

> State and timers are not yet supported in Beam's Python SDK.

It does not state the reason for this though ... is there an innate reason why this is not possible?

I am looking to implement a replay buffer / windowing system for a signal processing system that I am aiming to implement. Whereby a sliding window / historical frame buffer of features of length W is constantly updated with the latest window.

In Java its implementation looks like the following:

static class FeatureFrameBuffer extends DoFn, FeatureFrame> {
        Integer bufferSize;

```
    public FeatureFrameBuffer(Integer bufferSize) {
        this.bufferSize = bufferSize;
    }

    @StateId("buffer")
    private final StateSpec<BagState<KV<String, Double>>> bufferedFeatures = StateSpecs.bag();

    @StateId("count")
    private final StateSpec<ValueState<Integer>> countState = StateSpecs.value();

    @ProcessElement
    public void process(
                        ProcessContext context,
                        @StateId("buffer") BagState<KV<String, Double>> bufferState,
                        @StateId("count") ValueState<Integer> countState
                        ) {

        int count = firstNonNull(countState.read(), 0);
        count = count + 1;
        countState.write(count);
        bufferState.add(context.element());

        // Only output buffer if count is greater than bufferSize
        // Remove last element from buffer if count
        // greater than or equals buferSize
        if (count >= bufferSize) {
            bufferState.read();
            createFeatureFrame();
            context.output(featureFrame);
            bufferState.clear();
            countState.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering if the same could be achieved with the python sdk before I start to develop a custom implementation. Some advice on the matter would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, Python SDK support for Stateful Processing is still an open issue. see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2687, and it is blocked by [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-4594) ticket: "Implement Beam Python User State and Timer API", which is actively in progress though.

Comment: issue resolved: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2687

Answer (score 3):

User state and timers are available as of Beam release 2.9.0. The documentation has not yet been updated though.

Comment: The following document has more info: https://s.apache.org/beam-python-user-state-and-timers